# Question about winning at lottery

Tags: probability, statistics

I found this problem in a book:

> The following information about a lottery ticket is considered given: 
> A simple ticket, for which you can choose 6 numbers out of 49 available
> Every week there are two draws
> What is the probability of winning, on average, at least once a year if played
> weekly one simple ticket each, for 30 years? (a "win" is considered getting at least 3 numbers correct)

How can I solve this problem? I think that it's a Poisson distribution, but I don't know how to use this... Thanks!

Comment: OK, so we play a sinlge combination , right ? What is considered a "win" ? If we hit all the numbers , or at least three ?

Comment: Take it in stages.  What is the chance of winning one play?  How many plays in a year?  What is the chance of winning at least once in that many plays?  Then you have to do that $30$ times in a row.

Comment: @Peter. A "win" is considered when we hit at least three numbers.

Comment: @RossMillikan ok. So for a year I have 104 chances to win. We want that number of wins to be $\ge 1$ in a year. I think it is a binomial distribution. So, probability will be $1$ - probability to lose every time. It is ok for one year? And if I take $X_1, \dots, X_n$ to be r.v. that model the number of wins in year $i \in \{ 1, \dots, 30\}$, if I take $\bar{X} = \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_{30}}{30}$, this will give me the answer?

Comment: Actually, you have $~T = 52 \times 30~$ total events that might succeed, and you are looking for the probability that at least $~30~$ of these events succeed.  First, see [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), 
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$  Letting $~n = T, p = ~$ probability of success on a single event, and $~q = 1-p,~$ and denoting this last expression as $~f(k),~$ you want $$1 - \left[ ~\sum_{k=0}^{29} f(k) ~\right].$$

Comment: The one year computation is much simpler.  To lose $104$ times in a row is just the chance of one loss to the $104$ power.

Comment: @RossMillikan - I do not think you want the one-year calculation since it says "on average".  Instead you need the one play probability, and then the binomial probability of at least $30$ over $30$ years  (so at least $30$ over something like $30 \times 2 \times \frac{365.2425}{7}\approx 3130$ plays)

Comment: @Henry:  I missed the on average part, which makes yours the correct approach